# hierarchical structure query in mysql

Tags: mysql, hierarchical

```
-- PARENT_TABLE
seq     parent_id   name
0                   root
1       0           node1
2       1           node1_1
3       2           node1_1_1
4       1           node1_2
5       2           node1_1_2

-- CHILD_TABLE
id      name        flag
0       node1_1_1   true
1       node1_2     true
2       node1_1_2   false

-- Structure
(
        root
        └node1
          └node1_1
            └node1_1_1
            └node1_1_2
          └node1_2
    )
```

1. Only the leaf-free nodes of PARENT_TABLE are stored in CHILD_TABLE.
   (PARENT_TABLE.name == CHILD_TABLE.name)
2. PARENT_TABLE has a hierarchical structure.
3. What I want to find out
   I want to find all the names from PARENT_TABLE to their parents whose flag column in the CHILD_TABLE table is true
4. Example of desired results (no sorting)

`seq        parent_id   name
    3       2           node1_1_1
    2       1           node1_1
    1       0           node1
    0                   root
    4       1           node1_2`

Comment: What have you done so far? What is your expected output, and what you get instead? Or what is the error you get by running your SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can use a CTE:

```
WITH parents AS
(SELECT seq,parent_id,name FROM tblParent LEFT JOIN tblChild USING(name) WHERE flag
UNION ALL
SELECT c.seq,c.parent_id,c.name FROM tblParent AS c INNER JOIN parents ON parents.parent_id = c.seq)
SELECT * FROM parents
```